Is there a way to plot a grouped bar chart as well as not show white space which it leaves for bars with 0 heights?
I have a dataset where I need to plot it in a grouped bar chart but the dataset have so many datagaps that it leave traces/ space for bars with 0 heights.
I have tried converting the dataset from a wide form to long form and then did multilevel indexing and cleaned all the empty values as well.  After that I also tried clearing the year section as I though it may help with grouping I can show you what I have done.
So what my data set is like " I have 10 countries each country has data from years 2000-2021 now  what the issue is some countries have data in 2000 and not in other while other might have data in 2018,2019 only for which I did a multilevel indexing and sort the index hence the indexes are as follows then  'Country_Name' 'Years' and the a column named  'Value'  but then I can't seem to plot it efficiently in grouped bar chart.
The dataframe:




Country_Name
years
value




0
Afghanistan
2015
42.2


1
Bangladesh
2000
60.6


2
Bangladesh
2004
64.8


3
Bangladesh
2007
65.4


4
Bangladesh
2011
69.7


5
Bangladesh
2014
72.6


6
Bangladesh
2018
70.3


7
India
2006
69.1


8
India
2016
71.9


9
India
2021
74.1


10
Maldives
2009
42.6


11
Maldives
2017
29.8


12
Myanmar
2016
74.9


13
Nepal
2001
52.8


14
Nepal
2006
60.9


15
Nepal
2011
55.9


16
Nepal
2016
56


17
Pakistan
2007
39.7


18
Pakistan
2013
47


19
Pakistan
2018
48.6




You really need to add reproducible code and test data. Please choose between matplotlib and plotly, they are quite different libraries

In agreement with Johan's comment. Explaining what you did in words doesn't give us enough information to help you out, we really need to see your code and also your data set (or a small sample of it) so we can reproduce what you have tried to do.

@DerekO "https://github.com/ShrinidhiPareek/Python_Practice"this is the code file
I uploaded in  a repository on Github. I'm new to both the platforms so I don't know much about their working as of now . Please let me know if you can access it .Thank you I really appreciate your response.

@JohanC this is the link to the code https://github.com/ShrinidhiPareek/Python_Practice if you can explain how to plot this without data gaps popping as white spaces or bar with 0 heights . that will be really helpful thank you I really appreciate your response.

Your dataframe has a lot of emptyness.  You could combine the country and year columns to form a new column, and use that for plotting. E.g. plotting via pandas: df['Country & Year'] = df['Country_Name'] + ' ' + df['years'].astype(str); df.plot.bar(x='Country & Year', y='value'); plt.tight_layout(). Anyway, at StackOverflow you are supposed to add your best-effort code attempt and test data to the post itself, not at an external website.

@ShrinidhiPareek we're happy to help but you need to put enough information into the question so that we can reproduce your error. can you copy and paste some of the code from your jupyter notebook into the question itself? it's a lot of work to go through your jupyter notebook, copy the code, and try to run it on my own

@JohanC Thank you for your help and response I really appreciate and Thanks for explaining as well to how to write in a question ,I will keep that in mind in the future . I will try it out and will respond back . Thank you again :⁠-⁠)

@DerekO   Yes  I will do that I understand I didn't present my question properly . Will do so now . Thank you I'll respond back to you.

To get a stacked bar chart you can do the following:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the File
ds = pd.read_excel(file)

#Unstack the dataset such that each country name has a separate column
ds2 = ds.groupby(['years', 'Country_Name'])['value'].sum().unstack('Country_Name').fillna(0)

#Plot a stacked barchart
ds2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)

Figure: Annual composition of countries
